# Unable to write non redundant function

Tags: jquery, function

The following code is part of a function i wrote, but somehow it feels redundant. Could anyone show me how to properly approach the following:

```
openProject: function() {

    if( $(a).height() == $(b).height() ){

        $( myID )
        .css({ opacity: 0 })
        .show()
        .stop(true, true)
        .animate({ opacity: 1}, 750);

    }else{ /* end $(a).height() == $(b).height() */

        $( a ).stop(true, true).animate({ height : $( b ).height() }, 750, function(){

            $( myID )
            .css({ opacity: 0 })
            .show()
            .stop(true, true)
            .animate({ opacity: 1}, 750);

        });

    } /* end if:else */

}
```

The only difference between both parts is wether or not `$( a )` is animated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Knal

Comment: Extract the `$(myID)...;` part into a function declared above the if/else.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've slighty updated the code, to give a better  impression.

Comment: updated my answer ..check it out...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make a function :) and call it in both the palces

**updated code**

```
//seperate function
function myIdAnimate(){
    $( myID )
    .css({ opacity: 0 })
    .show()
    .stop(true, true)
    .animate({ opacity: 1}, 750);
 }

//your code
openProject: function() {

  if( $(a).height() == $(b).height() ){
     myIdAnimate(); //just call the function here
  }else{ /* end $(a).height() == $(b).height() */
     $( a ).stop(true, true).animate({ height : $( b ).height() }, 750, myIdAnimate()); //and here 
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for both of your replies. Would you still advise this when the code is already in another function? (see updated code)

This way i would get a lot of separate functions...

Comment: yes... seperating codes with function is better readable... :) :)..check out the updates yourself.. ;)....

Answer (score 2):

you just need to write a little function:

```
var resetIdSelector = function(idSelector){
   idSelector
     .css({ opacity: 0 })
     .show()
     .stop(true, true)
     .animate({ opacity: 1}, 750); 
}
```

and call it :

```
if( $(a).height() == $(b).height() ){
    resetIdSelector($(myID));
}else{ /* end $(a).height() == $(b).height() */
    $( a ).stop(true, true).animate({ height : $( b ).height() }, 750, function(){
       resetIdSelector($(myID));
    });

} /* end if:else */
```

Comment: Also a correct answer, thanks! 
Too bad i can only appoint one answer as the correct one...